# Typescript import suggestions (CTRL + .) don't populate on non-staged files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I use version `1.19.2` of Visual Studio Code. I can easily type the name of an import and type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to get a list of suggested imports.

However, when I add a *new* file to my project (eg: It has never been `get add`ed), <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> does not suggest anything, even though the name of the variable I am trying to import does in fact exist.

**Why does auto-import not work on unstaged files? How do I fix the problem?**